# inkwell does not work inside stack ->positionned

Tags: flutter

I am currently working on a desktop application (linux) using flutter, I noticed that when I put inkwell inside the positioned widget it does not work or maybe I made a mistake somewhere

```
//Home page
//there are many elements in the tree, but especially this part //that doesn't work. the expanded widgat has a row parent

 
  Stack(
                    clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                    children: [
                      Positioned(
                        top: 69,
                        left: 20,
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              width: 958,height: 400,
                              
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Container(
                                        width: 200,
                                        height: 200,
                                        padding:
                                            const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                                        child: InkWell(
                                          onTap: () {
                                            print('click');
                                          },
                                          child: IgnorePointer(
                                            child: Center(
                                                child: Text(
                                                    "voir plus (96 autres contacts)",
                                                    style:
                                                        bTextInfoItemBottomSearchCard)),
                                          ),),),],),],),),],),),],)
```

Comment: Please share more of your code. I tested this and it prints `click` as expected. Make sure there is no widget in the stack in front of your inkwell.

Comment: Can you include full widget tree, seems it is happening because of overlap

Answer (score 0):

Remove IgnorePointer widget from your code. It should work.